# $\varnothing$ as an initial segment of a partially ordered set. How to prove?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $(X, \leq)$ be a partially ordered set. $S \subseteq X$ is an intial segement of $X$ if $\forall x, y \in X: \ x \leq y, y \in S \Rightarrow x \in S$

Obviously, $X$ is an initial segment of itself. But what about $\varnothing$?

What can we do with if $y \in \varnothing$? How do we "deduce" from initially wrong statements?

Comment: The statement is vacuously true for $S=\varnothing$. Statement $y\in\varnothing\implies\Gamma$ is the same as $\neg y\in\varnothing\vee\Gamma$ wich is clearly true since $\neg y\in\varnothing$ is a true statement for every $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the following statement is not true:$$\exists x,y\in X\left[x\leq y\wedge y\in\varnothing\wedge x\notin\varnothing\right]$$

This because no $y\in X$ exists that satisfies $y\in\varnothing$.

That means that the following statement must be true:$$\neg[\exists x,y\in X\left[x\leq y\wedge y\in\varnothing\wedge x\notin\varnothing\right]]$$
This statement is actually the same as:$$\forall x,y\in X\left[x\leq y\wedge y\in\varnothing\implies x\in\varnothing\right]$$
So it states that $\varnothing$ is an initial segment of $X$.